# Installing Hammock Chair from Ceiling with Metal Joists

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, hanging, load

I’m mounting a hammock chair to my ceiling using 2 eye-bolt plates rated for 160 lbs max load. The plates came with 4 screws meant for wooden joists, but after drilling a pilot hole, I realized the apartment has metal joists.

Since I couldn’t find any info on how to properly mount anything heavy on a metal joist online, I was wondering if anyone here knows what I should do to properly mount the chair? I read about using metal-sheet screws or toggle screws, but since the metal joists are hollow, this doesn’t seem appropriate for a hammock chair (meant for light swinging, as it will be indoors)

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably ought to abandon the project at this point.  Metal joists can be surprisingly light gauge steel.  Sheet metal screws would not be strong and reliable enough for the pullout strength you need, especially holding a moving object.

Toggle bolts would probably be strong enough, I don't see the bolts ripping right out of the sheet metal, but I could see the sheet metal flexing enough to mess up the drywall and possibly deform the joist, which would be a very expensive repair.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in some apartment building or hanging in a large cased opening using a steel plate- if you're renting, I don't encourage it- if you're committed, and you're good at drywall repair, cut ack away from both sides and use one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MVGRX0Q)